# how to customize Laravel Filament Table size

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament, livewires

I try to change the size of table it is seem to large for me , I found only how to change TextColumn font size for every one in the table, only
but I do not find in net searh any thing about how I control the size of whole table , the row height , the font , the padding .. etc

Comment: https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/tables/layout#controlling-column-width-using-a-grid